# Search lines, pull specific data

Tags: python, text

I need to read a text file, search all lines, find a keyword in a specific location of the line and if it exists, pull other data from that same line.

My example is the word 'TRED'.  If TRED is at index location 95 I need to pull data from either certain columns or specific indexes from that line.

Currently my code is this....but it's not finding the word and so the results are all errors.

```
substr = "TRED"
with open(strFileLoc + "test.txt", 'r') as inputfile:
for line in inputfile:
    if line.find(substr, 95, 98) != -1:
        print(line.rstrip('\n'))
    else:
        print("There was an error at " + line.rstrip('\n'))
```

Comment: Why not immediately test `line[95:99] == 'TRED` instead? (Note the correct slice index...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to solve the problem. The issue (based on my quick test) is caused by the substring call you make: str.find() indexes from the first position you give to the last-1, so the substring you're looking for in this case would be 3 characters long (TRE) even if there would be a match at that position. So you could fix it by simply increasing the end position to 99.

However, find() also returns the position where it finds a substring, (-1) if not found. You could achieve a good outcome by searching without specifying a location and checking the return value instead, thus robustly handling the case of a shorter string.

```
substr = "TRED"
with open(strFileLoc + "test.txt", 'r') as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
        loc = line.find(substr)
        if loc == 95:
            print(line.rstrip('\n'))
        else:
            print("There was an error at " + line.rstrip('\n'))
```

Comment: Perfect. When I check the location of the text I want in the file it shows col 95, but the actual location is 94 (0 based?).  So I adjusted the location to search and was able to isolate the rows I want to look at.  Now I should be able to locate the data in those rows that I need to extract.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is an easier way to do this comparison. Check out the below code.

```
substr = "TRED"
with open(strFileLoc + "test.txt", 'r', 'r') as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
        if line[95:99] == substr:
            print(line.rstrip('\n'))
        else:
            print("There was an error at " + line.rstrip('\n'))
```

Ouput:

```
sdaksdkakslkdlaksjdlkajslkdjlkajklsfjslkdvnksdjjlsjdlfjlskldfjlsnvkjdglsjdfljalsmnljklasjlfaaaaTREDdjsalkjdlka
```

Make sure you are giving the proper index values.(Note: line[95:99], will take elements at 95,96,97,98 position only).

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm new to Python but not programming. Perhaps I'm not clear with what I need.  In my text file I need to look at the text beginning in column 95 and see if it matches my substr.  When I try your code I just get the error message on every line so it's not excluding the lines that DON'T have the substr.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you'd want to pull from either columns or indices on that line.
If your file is space, comma, tab, etc. separated you can split each line into columns very easily. Hence, you can do this:

```
substr = "TRED"
token_splitter = ',' # or whatever separator you have
column_number = 2
with open(strFileLoc + "test.txt", 'r', 'r') as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
        columns = line.rstrip().split(token_splitter)
        if columns[column_number] == substr: # get the exact column directly
            print(line.rstrip('\n'))
        else:
            print("There was an error at " + line.rstrip('\n'))
```